# Nginx failed to start. Cannot assign requested address?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

When I reboot my server (not nginx, the whole server), Nginx fails to start automatically. After I logged into the server, I can start nginx manually (service nginx start). It works. But if I restart again, I have to manually start Nginx. When checking the error.log for Nginx, I saw this error repeated several times :

```
2012/08/27 09:19:23 [emerg] 1066#0: bind() to [ipv6]:80 failed (99: Cannot assign requested address)
```

How can I fix this? What is this problem? (Im running an Ubuntu 12.04 server)

Comment: 1. `ifconfig`? 2. `grep listen /path/to/nginx.conf`?

Comment: @quanta added the outputs :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> bind() to [ipv6]:80 failed (99: Cannot
> assign requested address)

It sounds like your IPv6 address has just been assigned to eth0, and still be in the [tentative state](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4429.txt), thus Nginx cannot establish a listen on that IP.

Either turn of DAD ([Duplicate Address Detection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4862#section-5.4)) by running:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.eth0.dad_transmits=0
```

*(insert into `/etc/sysctl.conf` for permanent)*

or add this line into `/etc/network/interfaces`, under inet6 interface definition

```
post-up while ip -6 addr show tentative | grep . > /dev/null ; do sleep 1 ; done
```

Source: http://pyro.eu.org/how-to/micro/nginx-cannot-assign-requested-address-ipv6.txt

Comment: Thanks. What will be the best option out of the two? I also included the interfaces file on my server (please check the above question)

Comment: I think option 2 is better.

Comment: Why is option 2 better?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar symptoms, but a different configuration. The server runs Debian Wheezy with static IPv4 and IPv6 address configured.

```
# /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
 address 192.0.2.3
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 192.0.2.1

iface eth0 inet6 static
 address 2001:db8::3
 netmask 64
 gateway 2001:db8::1
```

At every boot, nginx failed to start:

```
bind() to [2001:db8::3]:80 failed (99: Cannot assign requested address)
```

Manually starting works fine and manual inspection also showed that the addresses and routes are set. Just setting the IPv6 address in `interfaces` (without the IPv4 address) worked. Removing the static IPv6 gateway also worked, but then a link-local gateway address is used. After further debugging, I found that the boot process would spit out:

```
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0.
```

It turns out that an IPv6 address and gateway is automatically assigned by the router when the interface is brought up. To avoid this behavior, set `accept_ra 0` in the `iface eth0 inet6` section. The `inet6` section has also to be moved before the `inet` section or the default route will still point to the link-local address.

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu 14.04 Hosts i just needed to move the IPv6 (inet6) entry BEFORE the IPv4 (inet) entry.

So this works:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet6 static
    address fd57:c87d:f1ee:2::6
    netmask 64
    up /sbin/ip -6 route add fd57:c87d:f1ee::/48 via fe80::1 dev $IFACE

iface eth0 inet static
   address 10.0.3.29
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   gateway 10.0.3.1
   dns-nameserver 10.0.3.1
```